# Join between two patterns

Tags: awk, sed

I have been searching for an answer to this but am not finding what works. This is what I am trying to accomplish. In a file I have lines that begin with a specific pattern and sometimes there is a line between them and other times there is not. I am trying join the line between the patterns to the first pattern line. Example below:

Current output:

```
Name: Doe John   
Some Random String  
Mailing Address: 1234 Street Any Town, USA
```

Note: The "Some Random String" line sometimes does not exist so the join would not be needed

Desired output:

```
Name: Doe John Some Random String  
Mailing Address: 1234 Street Any Town, USA
```

I have tried sed and awk answers I have found on the net but cannot wrap my head around how to make this work. My sed and awk skills are very basic at this point so I don't quite understand some of the solutions even when explained.

Thanks for any help or a point to documentation that talks about what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Good that you have mentioned that you have looks around forums, please do those efforts/codes in your question also, there is no right or wrong here as we all are for learning, adding efforts in questions is highly encouraged on SO, cheers.

Comment: Your file always contains only two or three lines?

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk  '{printf("%s%s",FNR>1 && $0~/^Mailing/?ORS:OFS,$0)} END{print ""}' Input_file
```

OR if you want to put new lines only for `Name` and `Mailing` both strings then try following.

```
awk  '
{
  printf("%s%s",FNR>1 && ($0~/^Mailing/ || $0 ~/Name:/)?ORS:OFS,$0)
}
END{
  print ""
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk  '        ##Starting awk program from here.    
{
  printf("%s%s",FNR>1 && ($0~/^Mailing/ || $0 ~/Name:/)?ORS:OFS,$0)
              ##Using printf to print strings, 1st one is either newline or space, which is based on
              ##condition if line is greater than 1 OR line is either starts with Mailing or has Name
              ##Then print ORS(newline) or print OFS(space). For 2nd string print current line.
}
END{          ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  print ""    ##Printing new line here.
}
' Input_file  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Very nice answer with a comprehensive explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Another awk where you define the *specific patterns*:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    p["Name"]              # define the specific patters that start the record
    p["Mailing Address"]
}
{
    printf "%s%s",(split($0,t,":")>1&&(t[1] in p)&&NR>1?ORS:""),$0
}
END {
    print ""               # conditional operator controls the ORS so needed here 
}' file
```

Output on slightly modified data (extra space comes from your data, didn't trim them):

```
Name: Doe John   Some Random String  
Mailing Address: 1234 Street Any Town, USA  Using: but not specific pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

How about a `GNU sed` solution:

```
sed '
/^Name:/{                               ;# if the line starts with "Name:" enter the block
N                                       ;# read the next line and append to the pattern space
:l1                                     ;# define a label "l1"
/\nMailing Address:/! {N; s/\n//; b l1} ;# if the next line does not start with "Mailing Address:"
                                        ;# then append next line, remove newline and goto label "l1"
}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/Name:/{:a;N;/Mailing Address:/!s/\s*\n\s*/ /;$!ta}' file
```

If a line contains `Name:` keep appending lines and replacing white space either side of the newline by a space, until the end of file or a line containing `Mailing Address:`.